# Fetching a resource in Java main method

Tags: java, resources, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to open a resource in my Java application by calling `MainClass.class.getResource("/Resources/file.extension")` and passing it to File's constructor with `getPath()`. Next, when I initialize a new `FileInputStream` with the `File`, I get a `FileNotFoundException`. The complete stack trace looks this.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Project name\build\classes\Resources\file.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at my.secret.project.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:27)
```

Here's my code.

```
File file = new File(MainClass.class.getResource("/Resources/file.extension").getPath());

...

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: Is the file present in the indicated location?

Comment: I would use `MainClass.class.getResourceAsInputStream(path)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your whole code can be replaced with simple:

```
InputStream in = MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/Resources/file.extension");
```

No need to use `File`. In fact the file on your CLASSPATH might be pointing to some location inside JAR/WAR, which definitely won't work. Have a loot at [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) for details.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Wait a few minutes and I'll accept it as an answer.